# asp.net check is primary key exists before inserting into table

Tags: asp.net, sql, insert, primary-key

looking for a simple way to check if a primary key already exists in the table before inserting into it. where Fname is the primary key in the table.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table] ([firstName], [lastName]) VALUES ('" + txtFName.Text + "','" + txtLName.Text + "')";        

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you should just try to insert. The dbms will return an error if they key exists. Trap that error.

You have to trap errors anyway, because there are a lot of things besides primary key constraints that can prevent a row from being inserted. Among them

- Any other kind of constraint, like a foreign key constraint, a check constraint, etc.
- Disk error.
- Network error.
- Hurricane.

You don't lose any efficiency by trapping the error.

- Inserting (no error) requires one round-trip to the database.
- Inserting (with error, which you trap) requires one round-trip to the database, not counting whatever you might have to do to correct that error.  You'd have to do all the correcting if you checked first anyway.
- Check-then-insert requires two round-trips to the database.

Some platforms can merge data if you try to insert a row for which a primary key already exists. The most famous (or most notorious, depending on your point of view) is [MySQL's ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: One of my clients was a pilot plant. They had an explosion that threw bolts almost 20 miles. Another time, a diesel generator explosion killed power to about a square mile of downtown.  So *trap* those errors. That's what I say.